# How flex itemRenderer works ? (their life cycle)

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

By works, i mean : how item renderer are instanciate , call , destroy... what is theire life cycle  ?

I had some display bugs, and this link open my mind to the problem 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=cellrenderer_072_14.html

( the doc is the same for flex3 )

But i want to know more. 
Any links or knowledge to share ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peter Ent wrote a series of blog posts on item renderers that is extremely useful:

itemRenderers: Part 1: inline renderers

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html

itemRenderers: Part 2: External renderers

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt2.html

itemRenderers: Part 3: Communication

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt3.html

itemRenderers: Part 4: States and Transitions

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt4.html

itemRenderers: Part 5: Efficiency

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt5.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :
http://sites.google.com/site/iamfuric/Home/Flex/about-itemrenderer
source code is available :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that link explains what you need to do: Don't ever assume state, and expect your itemrenderer to be reused for multiple items (so don't store data for one item at object level in the itemrenderer, only use variables inside your function)