# ItemRenderer Switching URLLoader Images

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, blackberry-playbook

I don't even know how to explain this behavior but I'll try. I am loading images from an external url that requires basic auth so I am using URLLoader to load the image from a unique ID. The ID gets passed to the itemrenderer which then proceeds to load the image. But the images switch around on their own when I scroll. If I load more than 7 images or so it starts repeating images....

Youtube video of error:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYoqlS14gWQ

Relevant code:

```
<s:ItemRenderer name="RandomItemRenderer" creationComplete="init();"
            xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="false">
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="hovered" />
    <s:State name="selected" />
</s:states>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.net.URLLoader;
        import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
        import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

        import mx.utils.ObjectProxy;

        import customclasses.Settings;

        [Bindable] private var coverArtImage:Image;
        private var myCoverArtLoader:URLLoader;

        [Bindable] private var coverArtSource:String;

        private function init():void {
            get_coverArt();
        }

        private function get_coverArt(): void {
            if (!data.coverArt) {
                set_nullCoverArt();
            } else {
                var requestString:String = "/rest/getCoverArt.view?v=1.5.0&c=AirSub&id=" + data.coverArt;
                var requestURL:String = Settings.ServerURL + requestString;

                myCoverArtLoader = new URLLoader();
                var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();

                var authHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader();
                authHeader.name = 'Authorization';
                authHeader.value = 'Basic ' + Settings.EncryptedCreds();

                myRequest.requestHeaders.push(authHeader);
                myRequest.url = requestURL;
                myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
                myCoverArtLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;

                myCoverArtLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, set_coverArt);
                myCoverArtLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, set_failedCoverArt);
                myCoverArtLoader.load(myRequest);
            }
        }

        private function set_coverArt(evt:Event) : void {
            coverArtImage = new Image();
            coverArtImage.source = myCoverArtLoader.data;           
            myCoverArtLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, set_coverArt);
        }

        private function set_nullCoverArt() : void {
            coverArtImage = new Image();
            coverArtImage.source = "assets/nullCoverArt.jpg";
        }

        private function set_failedCoverArt() : void {
            coverArtImage = new Image();
            coverArtImage.source = "assets/nullCoverArt.jpg";
            myCoverArtLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, set_nullCoverArt);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image source.normal="assets/coverOutline.png" source.selected="assets/coverOutlineYellow.png" source.hovered="assets/coverOutlineYellow.png"
         height="226" width="226" />

<s:VGroup top="4.5" bottom="5" width="200" horizontalAlign="center" letterSpacing="10"
          paddingBottom="5" paddingTop="9" verticalAlign="middle" x="13.5">
    <s:Image id="ui_imgCoverArt" width="200" height="200" source="{coverArtImage.source}"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.title}" width="160" styleName="RandomList" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ItemRenderers are reusable and cached, i.e. there are only limited count created in List to fill its area (rowCount +- couple). And when you scroll, new renderers are not instantiated, instead the one renderer that was scrolled out goes up or down and is filled with new data.

That's why you can not rely on `creationComplete` event, it will be fired only once for each instance of renderer.

The solution is to override `data` setter and build there the behaviour needed:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;
    get_coverArt();
}
```

Useful link: [How flex itemRenderer works ? (their life cycle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925889/how-flex-itemrenderer-works-their-life-cycle)

Comment: Ah did not know that - if you could provide a quick example or maybe a link on how to override data that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Is this supposed to make the performance super laggy? Does it go and get the Image each time the item is out of view and then back in view because that is what it looks like it is doing.

Comment: Well, it is up to you to optimize renderer, use static cache for already downloaded items, minimize creation of new objects, etc. Actually, I wonder 1) why you don't embed nullCoverArt.jpg and 2) why you use strange image loading and binding through `coverArtImage`. But all this suggestions deviate from the theme of this conversation.

Comment: Static caching may be a solution and I may use the SQLite database to store the images as well. As for the nullCoverArt - that is used when the server API (which I have no control over) returns an IO error for unavailable cover art. The coverArtImage function was the only way I could think of getting the images given the header basic auth. If there is a better way I would like to hear it so I change mine, and learn :)